# Beginners calculation with logarithms

Tags: logarithms

Given that $\log_{10}2 =0.3010$ and $\log_{10}3 = 0.4771$, evaluate the following without using mathematical tables or calculators

$(a) \log_{10} 81 $
$(b)\log_{10} 40 $

Comment: Is this title "Foundation of Maths" at all relevant to the subject matter?

Comment: why did you revert the edit i made?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. What do you know about logarithms that might help? Hint: factor $81$ and $40$. I am voting to close this question because you undid the formatting provided to help us help you.

Comment: i had typing error that's why.  but i need your help

Comment: remember that $\log(a^b) =b\log(a)$ and that $\log(a\cdot b) = \log(a)+\log(b)$

Comment: I presume that you know that $81= 9^2= 3^4$.  So you are asking for $\log_{10}(3^4)$.  What do you know about $\log(a^b)$? (Look at the previous comment.)  $40= 8*5= 2^3(5)$.  Unfortunately knowing that $log_{10}(3)= 0.4771$ does not help you here!  Knowing that $\log_{10}(5)= 0.6990$ helps a lot more.

Comment: @user247327, $40=4\times10$ is more useful here than $40=8\times5$.

Comment: Oops!  Yes, thank you!  I guess I am just too used to working with general logarithms and not specifically with base 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using various rules of logarithms, we have
$$\log_{10}(40)=\log_{10}(2^2\cdot 10)=\log_{10}(2^2)+\log_{10}(10)=2\log_{10}(2)+1.$$

I'm sure you can do the first one by a similar decomposition.